# Docker container not running properly. Exit status Code 255

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to start my localhost server (http://localhost:8080) on my mac using docker. I created a docker image with the following Dockerfile:

[image]

Then run the following docker command to create the image from my directory:

```
docker build -t packt-chp6 .
```

After the image was created, I ran the following docker command to start my localhost server:

```
docker run -d --name chat-app -v $PWD:/opt/app -p 8080:8080 packt-chp6
```

**The Problem**

Localhost server is unable to connect. When I list all my containers with the `-a` flag, I see the following:

[image]

I have deleted containers and build again from the scratch, and I still get the same result.

Thank you for the help. I appreciate...

Comment: Try running docker with -it options to see if you are able to get inside the docker and You can detach from a container and leave it running using the CTRL-p CTRL-q key sequence

Comment: Can you also run `docker logs chat-app`?

Comment: @zero298  I found out I had an error in my server.php script. I forgot to include a class. I have answered the question below. Prior to this discovery, I tried running docker stats and logs command but I didn't receive any output. My guess is since I had the -d flag in the docker run command, I didn't get a chance to see any errors. Removing the -d flag from the docker run command, printed out the errors on my terminal screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by running the following docker command without the -d flag

```
docker run --name chat-app -v $PWD:/opt/app -p 8080:8080 packt-chp6
```

Found out there was an error on my php server script, I wasn't including 'src/ChatComponent.php' file. Here is a sample of server.php

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'src/ChatComponent.php';

$app = new \Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080, '0.0.0.0');
$app->route('/chat', new \Packt\Chp6\Chat\ChatComponent);
$app->run();
```

After I included the file, it worked fine. Thanks